# How to embed a webcontent/portlet in the soy file - Liferay 7?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7.1, soy-templates

Is there a way to embed a web content or a portlet inside a soy file in Liferay? Can somebody share with me the codebase to proceed?

Thanks much in advance!

Comment: Maybe soy portlet is not the right place to embed another portlet...

Comment: I guess you could use the "Share" client side functionality to add some Liferay.Widget javascript code to embed a portlet.